# HTML: Is placing autonomous checkbox inside a button possible?

Tags: javascript, html

I've found several examples of placing another control inside a clickable button, but always with result that it's handlers are taken over by the parent button:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Button clicked')
};
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Checkbox clicked')
};
checkbox.onchange = evt => {
  alert('Checkbox changed')
};
```

```html
<button id="button" style="width: 150px;">
      ClickMe
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="float: right;" />
    </button>
```

I'm curious if the checkbox could somehow efface the surrounding button in the click event processing sequence, in another word if clicking directly on the checkbox would change it's state and stopped propagating the click, while clicking on the button anywhere except the checkbox would send click event to the button (I suppose if the button wasn't an active element it would be so)

Answer (score 1):

In your code please disable the button when you mouse over the checkbox,
and enable it when it is mouse out

code

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Button clicked')
};
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
/*...Add this line...*/
checkbox.onmouseover = evt => {
  button.disabled = true
};
checkbox.onmouseout = evt => {
  button.disabled = false
};
/*...Add this line...*/
checkbox.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Checkbox clicked')
};
checkbox.onchange = evt => {
  alert('Checkbox changed')
};
```

```html
<button id="button" style="width: 150px;">
      ClickMe
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="float: right;"/>
    </button>
```

Comment: Thanks, ypur code works in Chrome for me, but running it on Firefox Legacy, the embedded checkbox seems never get focus, which seems has been my issue. Is there a workaround for this? –

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you want the button to register provided that the checkbox is unchecked.
Have you tried using `!checkbox.checked` in an if statement when the button is clicked to allow/block the click.

Comment: I want the button behave normally, independent on the checkbox state, with the exclusion of area by the checkbox, which should behave independently on the button and vice versa. The absence of my snippet is the checkbox is always ignored, ie. Button clicked shows even if trying to change the check state.

Answer (score 0):

You can not click on the `checkbox` input without clicking the `button` because the `button` is not only clickable but also is the parent of `checkbox` input
but you can check if either the `checkbox` is check or not but using an if statement
like `(checkbox.checked)` for checked checkbox or `(!checkbox.checked)`

### Example

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Button clicked')
};
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.onclick = evt => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    alert('Checkbox is checked');
  } else {
    alert('Checkbox is unchecked');
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button" style="width: 150px;">
  ClickMe
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="float: right;" />
</button>
```

Or if you want the `button` do not raise pop while checkbox is checked or uncheck you can simply disable the button for short time while `checkbox` is clicked but you won't use an alert in that case you'll use `confirm` in order to get set condition based on the `checkbox` pop

### Example

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = evt => {
  alert('Button clicked')
};
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.onclick = evt => {
  button.setAttribute('disabled', '');
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    x = confirm('Checkbox is checked');
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        if (x || !x) {
          button.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
        }
      }, 100);
  } else {
    confirm('Checkbox is unchecked');
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        if (x || !x) {
          button.removeAttribute('disabled', '');
        }
      }, 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button" style="width: 150px;">
  ClickMe
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="float: right;" />
</button>
```